# Laravel 5.2 How to incorporate the built-in Authentication system to a project which has almost been done

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I've been teaching myself Laravel5.2, and am now learning the Authentication.
Laravel offers built-in Authentication systems, but apparently this should be introduced at the beginning of the development.

What if I want to introduce this authentication framework to a project, which has already been built and has a lot of functionalities?

I bought a book about Laravel 5, but apparently this doesn't give hints to accomplish this task.

I believe that incorporating the authentication systems to a project, which has already been made, is possible. However, I'm a little clueless, since there are not many information resources which are not out-dated out there.

I'd appreciate if you'd give any idea.

(Chances are that I should create authentication logic by pure PHP. I haven't tried it, but maybe it's a good experience)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem here. You will just need to rewrite some parts of you app. You can find really good tutorial on built-in Auth system inside the 'Easy Laravel 5' book.